# Left aligning a displayed equation in plain TeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, plain-tex

This one seems to be a rather simple question but right now I just run out of ideas. I simply want to left align a displayed equation using plain TeX, that is, I want the equation to start from the very left of the page but with the usual size of a displayed equation (thats why using just one '$' doesn't work). Please help!

Comment: How about: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 i=10$?

Comment: @someonr OMG now I feel so stupid! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\displaystyle` iside `$ formular $`.

## Example

```
Left aligned formular:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^4 i=10$
\bye
```

## Result

[image: result]